# Does material-ui release naming follows semantic versioning naming convention?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Do material-ui versions follow semantic versioning naming convention where when breaking change happens the version's major figure is increased?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> Material-UI strictly follows Semantic Versioning 2.0.0.

From https://material-ui.com/discover-more/changelog/

Comment: Cool. Although it really surprises me that it's only third time breaking change happened since release of mui v1.

Comment: It was only a year ago (May 2018) that 1.0 was released: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v1.0.0.   [3.0 was 3 months later](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v3.0.0) and there wasn’t a 2.0 (explained here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v3.0.0). The intent is to have a major release every 6-12 months going forward.